# Replace hard-coded values in stored procedure with values from table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with hard-coded values in it (`CASE statement`). Now these hard-coded values are already stored in a different table so I would like the retrieve them from the table instead of having them hard-coded in the Stored Procedure.
In other words, I want to replace the values in the `CASE` and retrieve them from the table. I'm not sure how to go about this.
This is the table that contains the values.

EDIT: The values in the table will often change. (Ex: Let's say I change the other_value from 25 to 35).  When executed, I want the stored procedure to dynamically retrieve the (currently hard-coded values) from the table.  (Ex: the value 25 would be replaced by 35 in the stored procedure because it will have been dynamically changed upon execution). Instead of having 10, 25, 30 as values directly hard-coded in the stored procedure, I replace them with variables(?) that will contain the current contents of the table I have for these values.

[image]

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Update_Proc]
AS
BEGIN

Update dbo.MyTable
 set Nb1=0, Nb2=0, Nb3= b.TotalAmount, MaxValue =
   CASE   WHEN b.TotalAmount < 10                               THEN 25
          WHEN b.TotalAmount >= 10  and b.TotalAmount < 20      THEN 50
          WHEN b.TotalAmount >= 20  and b.TotalAmount < 30      THEN 100

   END

From  dbo.Client_stuff cmta
   INNER Join otherTable b
   ON b.someValue=cmta.someValue
        where yesInd=1

END
```

Comment: Something here not clear, what exactly you trying to achieve?

Comment: As posted your question doesn't have enough details to help here. I get the gist of what you are trying to do but there just isn't enough information to offer any assistance. You should however stop using the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix I would recommend either changing the prefix to something else or even better, drop the notion of a prefix entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is passing parameters to a stored procedure. I can only speculate on this with what you've provided though.
The below achieves this:

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Update_Proc] @int1 int , @int2 int
AS
BEGIN

Update dbo.MyTable
set Nb1=0, Nb2=0, Nb3= b.TotalAmount, MaxValue =
CASE   WHEN b.TotalAmount < @int1                               THEN 25
      WHEN b.TotalAmount >= @int1  and b.TotalAmount < @int2      THEN 50
      WHEN b.TotalAmount >= @int2  and b.TotalAmount < 30      THEN 100

END

From  dbo.Client_stuff cmta
INNER Join otherTable b
ON b.someValue=cmta.someValue
    where yesInd=1

END
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I get the values of the parameters?   How would I retrieve them from the table.  With another stored procedure?

Comment: oh I see, then you would want to do a sub select. so WHEN b.TotalAmount < (SELECT col1 from Tablevalues WHERE pkid = yourvalueid)  You would have to include a pk in your value table

Comment: yes that's what I want to do!!!!   However, I wouldn't know in advance the total amount of rows that the table has.  I would use an iterator to go through the rows?

Comment: ok so just for clarity. At any given time how many rows are in the values tables? Am I correct in thinking 1 row and you change the values of this row?

Comment: actually, right now, in the table I used above as an example, there are 3 rows but more rows with values might be added as time goes by. Note that this stored procedure would not change any values in the table, only retrieve values.

Comment: In this case I don't think it can be done with the current table. You either need to delete the current data before inserting the new one or better still add a new column 'timestamp' that uses the function GETDATE() to insert the current time of inserting and then you would order on this.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure how this applies here.  In this stored procedure, the values in the 'case statement' are only retrieved, they are never modified.